# How to make a 4G USB modem to be detected as a normal network card

Tags: networkmanager

How to make a 4G USB modem to be detected as a normal network card (wired connection)? Now I connect the modem (not HiLink, just the modem), in NetworkManager I choose "mobile connection", it connects but `ip a` shows it as "ppp".

Upd: Maybe there is a way to create a virtual NIC and then convert to ppp?

Comment: You can't - it's not a network card, it's a modem. It doesn't connect to an ISP with TCP/IP protocol, it connects to a phone company's system using PPP protocol. You need to set it up as a modem / mobile broadband interface according to instructions appropriate for your Linux distro / UNIX variant.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I understand that, but maybe there is a way to create a virtual NIC and then convert to ppp?

Comment: Um - convert what exactly to PPP? You can't convert TCP/IP to PPP - TCP/IP works on Layer 3, PPP on Layer 2; L3 protocols run on top of L2 protocols. You _must_ have a L2 connection between devices before L3 connection can be formed. I don't understand what exactly are you hoping to achieve.

Comment: So if you could please expand your question and explain a few things: 1) What exactly are you trying to achieve? 2) Why exactly are you doing it this way instead of using the modem as a modem? 3) What exactly is your OS? 4) What exactly is this modem? 5) Do you have a SIM card in the modem? 6) Does that SIM card work for example with a phone?

Comment: @Peregrino69 There are 4G modems Huawei stick and HiLink. HiLink is a router and a modem at the same time, which when connected is defined as a wired connection, not ppp. I am interested in creating a similar "virtual router" by means of the operating system.

Comment: There's nothing "virtual" about the modem's routing capability. It takes traffic in from one interface / subnet and forwards it out from the other interface into the other subnet. HiLink appears to be a Huawei app used to manage a variety of Huawei devices, nothing more. What you're now saying sounds a lot like you want to have the functionality of the app available on a *NIX OS - to do that you need to reverse-engineer HiLink app and code your own. To even try to do that on OS level requires deep level info about the functionality of the device and the app; very much confidential info.

Comment: What you can try is create an Ethernet-over-USB interface on your system. That might get the basic connectivity between your system and the 4G stick working - can't guarantee as have never tried, and don't have a 4G stick to play with. That won't give you the phone company connection yet. Having answers to the questions would be good; it's kinda useful to understand the goal and what one's working with when trying to help someone. Please don't answer in comments, update your question instead so the relevant info is available for community members without going through long comment threads.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045537/create-new-ethernet-usb-network-interface-on-linux)'s a bit of info about creating an Eth-over-USB interface. I'd also check the distro documentation for distro-specific info.

Comment: @Peregrino69 HiLink is just an example and I don't need it. I need, as you wrote above: "It takes traffic in from one interface / subnet and forwards it out from the other interface into the other subnet". I.e. to take data from one interface and transfer it to another (e.g. some virtual ethernet)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is really confusing. Taking data from one interface and transferring it out another is the only function the device has. Eth-over-USB allows your Linux box to forward Ethernet traffic out of USB port, whereupon the modem will receive it. It would be kinda useful to understand what exactly is the end goal. Answers to the questions would take a long way to that direction. Please don't answer in a comment, update your question so the relevant information is easily available for other community members who might want to pitch in, without the need to go through long commentary.

Comment: @seccomp2 how about you give some concrete information (the make and model of your modem, lsusb -v). You and your discussion partner talk about a lot of abstract things and make a lot of tiresome assumptions that will take a lot to correct (ppp DOES create a virtual interface, 4G modems do NOT all work the same, some appear *exactly* like an ethernet or wifi dongle when plugged in, etc).

Comment: I guess that the best thing you could is to chuck that 4G modem and use a regular android phone instead, which (with its default settings) will give you an CDC interface (acting exactly like an ethernet one) when connected via an usb cable and set to "USB tethering" mode.

Comment: @UncleBilly I thought there was some ready-made universal solution, how to make an ethernet interface from a modem which is defined as a ppp interface, but I was wrong. Instead of an android phone, it is easier to use a 4G modem like Huawei HiLink, which is defined as a network card.

Comment: So, I gather that the make and model of your modem is state secret or something? Or are you afraid that the solution may be something banal, like installing usb_modeswitch (or adding your modem to its list of recognized devices) and switching your device to CDC mode? Also, that's not clear what your problem with `ppp` is and why you cannot just use it that way: `pppX` is a network interface just like `ethX` or `usbX`; it should make no difference unless you're using some broken software which assigns deep meanings to those names (which are actually purely arbitrary).

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need a huge workaround to get the result that you are looking for.
Basic language not to be complex. Use another way for it.
https://github.com/MBRO95/PortableCellNetwork
This gets the same result done.
Otherwise reverse tethering or configuring the usb0 etc ports is a headache not worth it.